# Cant remove row with trigger in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

Whenever a student’s popularity is updated and becomes < 50, the student should be removed from the team “x” .

```
UPDATE student
SET popularity = 52
WHERE id = 2;
```

Result: no such column: popularity

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I use db browser Sql Lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a reference to `NEW`.  So I think the logic is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER UPDATE ON student
FOR EACH ROW
when new.popularity < 50
begin 
    delete from ismember
        where new.id = ismember.sid and team = 'cool_guys';
end;
```